# Dragging cell references to different worksheet across the rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to link every cell in 3 columns to corresponding cells in a different worksheet. While I am able to pick up the first cell reference just fine, when I drag the reference down the column in each of the 3 columns, instead of picking up cell reference in a sequence (i.e. c1, c2, c3 etc) the information just gets copied (i.e. c1, c1, c1 ) for all the cells in that column.

Is there a way to automate this instead of manually changing the cell references. I have about 200 rows for each of the 3 columns.

Comment: That isn't behavior that I can replicate.  Are you sure your cell references aren't absolute?  (i.e $c$1)

Comment: right click drag - fill series

Comment: Thanks guys, Adam - you were right, the cell was being absolutely referenced. Removing that made it work. Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel - can't get the formula to copy correctly](http://superuser.com/questions/633623/excel-cant-get-the-formula-to-copy-correctly)